# Flatpickr rangePlugin: days between disabled days are selectable

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr v4.5.1. with rangePlugin.
On first selection everything is ok (image 1). Days between disabled days are disabled and can not selected. But opens the pickers again, then are these days selectable (image 2).

[image]
[image]